# CMD list all files of multiple drives (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, cmd

I am looking for a cmd command to **list all files** (by this command `dir /s /b /o:gn`) of **all existing drives** `(C: D: E: ....)`

I am currently using dirty C / C++ code to do it. I list all drives by this:

```
DWORD test = GetLogicalDriveStrings( mydrives, lpBuffer);
      for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
        // lpBuffer[i] shows the drives
```

and list the files by this

```
system(("dir -d " + lpBuffer[i] + " /s /b /o:gn >> files87435vttv8r").c_str());
```

**Is there a way to do it just in CMD?**

*In relation to Compo's comment:*

I want to list all files like `dir /s /b /o:gn`, but this is just working for the current drive (`C: or D: ...`) (Only all files from one drive are shown). **I want to modify this command to list all files from ALL drives (C: and D: and all available drives)**

An example output of the command I am looking for:

```
C:\Users\root\test\bla.txt
C:\Users\root\Desktop\folder\myfile.txt
D:\analysis\mytext.docx
F:\docs\test.docs
```

The shown files are all from different drives.

Comment: Is your question, how do I get all logical drive letters? Because you already seem to have posted a method for listing all of your files in a specific format. If so, please edit your question to make that clear, and remove anything which isn't necessary. Oh, and please use the search facility at the top of the page, you're not the first person to have needed all logical drive letters before.

Comment: @Compo I edited my question and made it clear.

Comment: to get all hard disks: `wmic logicaldisk where drivetype="3" get caption`

Comment: @Stephan Yeah thank you :) But my question is about showing the files from ALL hard disks.

Comment: `dir` isn't able to search for drives on it's own (You can do `dir c:\* d:\*`, but you'd have to know the available drives beforehand). Put the `wmic` command into a `for /f` loop with proper tokens to get the drives and do a `dir` for each of them.

Comment: @Jakob, `dir` doesn't output like that either, so you'll need to use another method, or find a way to modify its output to match your specific requirements. Then loop over your drive list, executing your listing command.